# Razor will not render hidden accurate PK in HiddenFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Running into a weird problem in my ASP MVC 4 site. If the user opens the `create` form and attempts to add an agent to our database, we naturally run validation on the fields first. If there is an error, we save the agent in incomplete status, and redirect the user back to the create page.

The error comes when the user attempts to re-save the agent. On the first post-back, the agent is saved into the database and a PK is generated. On the second post-back, however, the PK is being sent to the server with a value of `0` instead of what was just auto-generated.

I've added a `HiddenFor` on the `Create` view, however this renders with a value of `0` each and every time.

I've also stepped through the code to make sure that the PK is being generated after the `.Save` is called, is still present when `return View` is called and also ensured that the `Model.ID` property contains the same value when the view is being rendered.

Regardless, if I right click the page and view the source, the hidden field renders like so:

```
<input data-val="false" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
```

**Model**

```
public partial class AgentTransmission
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**View**

```
@model MonetModelFromDb.Models.AgentTransmission

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create new Agent";
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedDate, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedOperator, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferenceNumber, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Region, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.INDDist, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastChangeDate, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastChangeOperator, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EditTaxId, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParentId, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsSubstat, new { data_val = "false" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID, new { data_val = "false" })
```

**Rendered HiddenFor Section**

```
<input data-val="false" data-val-date="The field CreatedDate must be a date." id="CreatedDate" name="CreatedDate" type="hidden" value="" />
<input data-val="false" id="CreatedOperator" name="CreatedOperator" type="hidden" value="" />
<input data-val="false" id="Region" name="Region" type="hidden" value="NM-834" />
<input data-val="false" id="INDDist" name="INDDist" type="hidden" value="834" />
<input data-val="false" data-val-date="The field LastChangeDate must be a date." data-val-required="The LastChangeDate field is required." id="LastChangeDate" name="LastChangeDate" type="hidden" value="4/8/2015 10:43:30 AM" />
<input data-val="false" id="LastChangeOperator" name="LastChangeOperator" type="hidden" value="TYPCLS" />
<input data-val="false" data-val-required="The EditTaxId field is required." id="EditTaxId" name="EditTaxId" type="hidden" value="False" />
<input data-val="false" data-val-number="The field ParentId must be a number." id="ParentId" name="ParentId" type="hidden" value="" />
<input data-val="false" data-val-required="The IsSubstat field is required." id="IsSubstat" name="IsSubstat" type="hidden" value="False" />
<input data-val="false" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [MonetAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Create(AgentTransmission agenttransmission, bool andAddAgent = false)
    {
    .
    .
    .
        //Determine if this is first POST or not
        if (agenttransmission.ID > 0)
        {
            db.Entry(agenttransmission).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            db.AgentTransmission.Add(agenttransmission);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        //Send back to view if errors pressent
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorMsg))
        {
            return View(agenttransmission);
        }           
    }
```

**EDIT**

If I remove the `HiddenFor` helper and simply cut/paste the rendered `input` tag, I'm able to capture the corret PK value. However, this is a little hacky so I was hoping to find a more elegant solution (if possible)

```
<input data-val="false" id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="@Model.ID" />
```

Comment: I remember running into something weird like that in the past and ended up rendering the field directly instead of using the helper.  if you put <input type="hidden" value="@Model.ID" /> on your view does it show the correct id then?

Comment: Yes, it does, however I was hoping to find a more elegant solution... if that's possible.

Comment: I tried several different things but wasn't ever successful getting it to work in those situations.  Always just worked around it.  Hopefully someone else will have a more elegant solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variations on this question are asked here frequently. Basically it boils down to the `ModelState` object and the fact that its values override values on the actual model for the view. When you post the form, `0` is set in the `ModelState` object for your `ID` property. In the post action, you save the entity, which causes its `ID` property to be updated, but `0` is still in `ModelState`. When you return the view, `0` is set as the value for `ID` again, because, again, that's what's in `ModelState`.

The reason why it works this way is best explained by an example. Let's say you have a form where you're editing an existing entity, which has a `Name` property that's set to "Foo". The user changes this in the form to "Bar" and then posts the form. However, they neglected to fill in a required field, so the error prevents their update from being saved. What should happen at this point? If we use the model value, the `Name` field will be reset to "Foo". However, if `ModelState` is used, the `Name` field retains the user's modification of "Bar". In the latter case, they merely fix the error and post again. In the former, they must remake all the changes they made to the form previously, which would obviously be a very poor user experience.

Now, as to how to fix this. The best way is to follow the PRG pattern (Post-Redirect-Get). If the submission is good, and you saved the changes successfully, then don't return the view, even if you want the user to be able to immediately make additional changes. If you want that, simply redirect back to the same action, but the redirect process is enough to clear the `ModelState` so that user is now interacting with the updated model pulled fresh from the database.

If that's not doable, then you can simply clear the `ModelState`. I would advise against clearing it completely, as you can cause some very real user frustration as detailed in the example above. If you really can't do a redirect, then try to only clear the values in `ModelState` you really need to.

```
ModelState.Remove("ID");
```